# Saving data to a database

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have this action and I wish to save, `$newtkamount` to the database, I've tried using the same code I used for my register page (obviously point to the different table) but I can't get anything to work on this. It needs to over write the value that already exists based on the current users user ID

```
public function actionBuy($qty=0) {
    $_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    $model = Tokens::model()->findByAttributes(array('UserID' => $_id));
    if ($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, "Keep calm! If you havent bought tokens before this is normal");


    $this->render('buy', array(
        'model' => $model,));

    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST'){
        $_qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $newtkamount = ($model->TokenAmount + $_qty);

        echo $newtkamount . $model->TokenAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: in which column you want to save the value for $newtkamount ?

Comment: It's called TokenAmount but it needs to over write the existing value based upon user ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always render after saving data and dont use `echo` in controllers.

```
public function actionBuy($qty=0) {
    $_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    $model = Tokens::model()->findByAttributes(array('UserID' => $_id));
    if ($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, "Keep calm! If you havent bought tokens before this is normal");

    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST'){
        $_qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $model->TokenAmount = ($model->TokenAmount + $_qty);
        $model->save(false);
    }

    $this->render('buy', array(
        'model' => $model));
}
```

Comment: Echo is simply for testing purpose to show correct values are going where I want them

Comment: thats ok...try using this code for your problem in saving data